# Server does not accept my multipart/form-data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, http

I try to upload an image to my webservice from my iphone application. The webservice is programmed in php. I have to send the image along with a device_id as multipart/form-data.

Something is wrong with my request because the server does not accept my device_id (invalid format). I am 100% positive that the device_id is correct because it works with my other requests.

I think there is something wrong with my request structure because Charles proxy cannot decode the multipart form-data.

Here is my request (sniffed with charles proxy):

```
POST /api/profile/update HTTP/1.1
Host: THE_URL
User-Agent: SeduceMe/1.0 CFNetwork/548.0.3 Darwin/11.2.0
Content-Length: 6639
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------255141413922088
Accept-Language: de-de
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: PHPSESSID=tlcpnqugcpgs0skh3l2ip9ujh7
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

---------------------------255141413922088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device_id"

mgs2AHyvfIcSXHSKE+0eHA==
---------------------------255141413922088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form[file]"; filename="avatar.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

RAW_JPEG_DATA
---------------------------255141413922088--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a great wrapper to post form/data. it is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

please look at ASIFormData

thanks/

Comment: Just a warning, ASI is no longer being maintained and is not ARC compatible. While it's still great, if you're just starting a project you may want to seek other wrapper classes for NSURLRequest/NSConnection

Comment: @MishieMoo hi, yes it is not ARC compatible most possibly you know  you can still use it in ARC projects with flag -fno-objc-arc and it works like a charm. thanks.

Comment: thanks I found my bug inside their sourcecode: boundary has to be: 255141413922088